# Filter Pyspark Dataframe column based on whether it contains or does not contain substring

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe `message_df` with millions of rows that looks like this

| id | message |
| --- | --- |
| ab123 | Hello my name is Chris |
| cd345 | The room should be 2301 |
| ef567 | Welcome! What is your name? |
| gh873 | That way please |
| kj893 | The current year is 2022 |

and two lists

```
wanted_words = ['name','room']
unwanted_words = ['welcome','year']
```

I only want to get rows where `message` contains any of the words in `wanted_words` and does not contain any of the words in `unwanted_words`, hence the result should be:

| id | message |
| --- | --- |
| ab123 | Hello my name is Chris |
| cd345 | The room should be 2301 |

As of right now I am doing it word by word

```
message_df.select(lower(F.col('message'))).filter(
    (
        F.col('lower(message)').contains('name') |
        F.col('lower(message)').contains('room') 
    ) & (
        ~F.col('lower(message)').contains('welcome') &
        ~F.col('lower(message)').contains('year') 
    )  
)
```

Which is very tedious to code. However, when I instead use `rlike`:

```
wanted_words ="(name|room)"
unwanted_words ="(welcome|year)"

message_df.select(lower(F.col('message'))).filter(
   ~F.col('lower(message)').rlike(not_contain) &
    F.col('lower(message)').rlike(contain)
)
```

The process slows down immensely. Is the reason because `rlike` is significantly slower, and if so what is a better way of filtering when `wanted_words` and `unwanted_words` may contain hundreds of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split text into tokens/words and use [arrays_overlap](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap.html#pyspark.sql.functions.arrays_overlap) function to check if wanted or unwanted token is present:

```py
df = df.filter(
    (
      F.arrays_overlap(
          F.split(F.regexp_replace(F.lower("message"), r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", ""), "\s+"),
          F.array([F.lit(c) for c in wanted_words])
          )
    )
    & 
    (
      ~F.arrays_overlap(
          F.split(F.regexp_replace(F.lower("message"), r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", ""), "\s+"),
          F.array([F.lit(c) for c in unwanted_words])
          )
    )
)
```

Full example:

```py
columns = ["id","message"]
data = [["ab123","Hello my name is Chris"],["cd345","The room should be 2301"],["ef567","Welcome! What is your name?"],["gh873","That way please"],["kj893","The current year is 2022"]]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)

wanted_words = ['name','room']
unwanted_words = ['welcome','year']

df = df.filter(
    (
      F.arrays_overlap(
          F.split(F.regexp_replace(F.lower("message"), r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", ""), "\s+"),
          F.array([F.lit(c) for c in wanted_words])
          )
    )
    & 
    (
      ~F.arrays_overlap(
          F.split(F.regexp_replace(F.lower("message"), r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", ""), "\s+"),
          F.array([F.lit(c) for c in unwanted_words])
          )
    )
)

[Out]:
+-----+------------------------+
|id   |message                 |
+-----+------------------------+
|ab123|Hello my name is Chris  |
|cd345|The room should be 2301 |
+-----+------------------------+
```

You can also pre-compute the tokens at once for efficiency:

```py
df = df.withColumn("tokens", F.split(F.regexp_replace(F.lower("message"), r"[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+", ""), "\s+"))
```

and use in "arrays_overlap":

```py
F.arrays_overlap(F.col("tokens"), F.array([F.lit(c) for c in wanted_words]))
```